# R Verbose output on extraction of Coefficients

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm getting a lot of verbose output when assigning a set of coefficients to a dataframe.

I've tried using suppressMessages but this does seem to work, maybe I'm not applying it correctly?

Code Example is:

```
sign_pre$model7 <- reg1_model$coefficients[1]
                   reg1_model$coefficients[2]*sign_pre$length
                   reg1_model$coefficients[3]*sign_pre$soc
```

Thanks

Arden

Comment: needs a minimum working example

Comment: Not quite following you John. Do I need to supply more code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Found it

```
sign_pre$model7 <- reg1_model$coefficients[1]
                   invisible(reg1_model$coefficients[2]*sign_pre$length)
                   invisible(reg1_model$coefficients[3]*sign_pre$soc)
```